# Could someone tell me what's wrong with my understanding about $var(Y)$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, variance

Suppose $X$ is equally likely to take three values: $−1, 0, +1$.

Let $Y = X^2$.The probability mass function for random variable Y is $P(Y=0)=\frac 13$ and $P(Y=1)=\frac 23$

Here is the thing, when I calculate the variance of Y

$$var(Y)=E(Y^2)-(E(Y))^2$$

Using the given equation, the result I got was $E(Y)=E(Y^2)$. That makes the $var(Y)<0$ which is wrong. Could someone show me what's wrong with my calculation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $E[Y^2]=E[Y]=\frac 23\implies Var[Y]=\frac 23-\frac 49>0$.

Comment: How does $E(Y)=E(Y^2)$ cause the variance to be negative?

Comment: Perhaps you think $x^2>x$? This is not true for $0 \leq x \leq 1$.